# Additional legend (entries)

Tags: pgfplots

As my `colorbar` contains only few values, I want to use further legend entries instead of a `colorbar`.

How can I (1) add additional entries to the existing legend or (2) add a second legend, which contains the entries for the used colors.

(As different marks are used, I guess it is best to use an `area legend` for the colors. Or someone might come with a better idea.)

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\pgfplotstableread{
x y z1 z2
5 5 1  1
6 6 1  2
7 7 2  1
8 8 2  2
}\mytable

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    colorbar,
    colorbar style={ytick={1,2},ylabel={z2}},
    legend pos=north west
]

\addplot [scatter,scatter src=\thisrow{z2},only marks,mark=*]         table [restrict expr to domain={\thisrow{z1}}{1:1}] {\mytable};
\addplot [scatter,scatter src=\thisrow{z2},only marks,mark=triangle*] table [restrict expr to domain={\thisrow{z1}}{2:2}] {\mytable};

\legend{$z1=1$,%
        $z1=2$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Update:**

I'm struggling at finding the correct colors.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\pgfplotstableread{
x y z1 z2
5 5 1  1
6 6 1  2
7 7 2  3
8 8 2  4
9 9 2  5
}\mytable

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    legend pos=north west,
    scatter,
    scatter src=explicit,
    point meta=explicit,
    only marks
]

\addplot [mark=*]         table [meta=z2,restrict expr to domain={\thisrow{z1}}{1:1}] {\mytable};
\addplot [mark=triangle*] table [meta=z2,restrict expr to domain={\thisrow{z1}}{2:2}] {\mytable};

\legend{$z1=1$,%
        $z1=2$}

\addlegendimage{area legend,color=blue,fill}
\addlegendentry{$z2=1$}
\addlegendimage{area legend,color=black,fill}
\addlegendentry{$z2=2$}
\addlegendimage{area legend,color=black,fill}
\addlegendentry{$z2=3$}
\addlegendimage{area legend,color=black,fill}
\addlegendentry{$z2=4$}
\addlegendimage{area legend,color=red,fill}
\addlegendentry{$z2=5$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `\addlegendimage` to add entries. This can be customized to show whatever you like. How should these additional entries look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible way. Use `\addlegendimage`. I use flexible version that allows you to adjust the `legend image code` to get whatever you have in mind.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\pgfplotstableread{
x y z1 z2
5 5 1  1
6 6 1  2
7 7 2  1
8 8 2  2
}\mytable

\pgfplotsset{my legend/.style={
    legend image code/.code={
        \fill [#1] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.4cm);
    },
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
%     colorbar,
%     colorbar style={ytick={1,2},ylabel={z2}},
    legend pos=north west
]

\addplot [scatter,scatter src=\thisrow{z2},only marks,mark=*]         table [restrict expr to domain={\thisrow{z1}}{1:1}] {\mytable};
\addplot [scatter,scatter src=\thisrow{z2},only marks,mark=triangle*] table [restrict expr to domain={\thisrow{z1}}{2:2}] {\mytable};

\legend{$z1=1$,%
        $z1=2$}

\addlegendimage{my legend=blue}
\addlegendentry[blue]{groundhogs}
\addlegendimage{my legend=red}
\addlegendentry[red]{koalas}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for your updated question: the colors are derived from the color map. So you could just use this to color the legends.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\pgfplotstableread{
x y z1 z2
5 5 1  1
6 6 1  2
7 7 2  3
8 8 2  4
9 9 2  5
}\mytable

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    legend pos=north west,
    scatter,
    scatter src=explicit,
    point meta=explicit,
    only marks
]

\addplot [mark=*]         table [meta=z2,restrict expr to domain={\thisrow{z1}}{1:1}] {\mytable};
\addplot [mark=triangle*] table [meta=z2,restrict expr to domain={\thisrow{z1}}{2:2}] {\mytable};

\legend{$z1=1$,%
        $z1=2$}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,5}
{\pgfplotscolormapdefinemappedcolor{\the\numexpr(#1-1)*250}
\colorlet{leg#1}{mapped color}
\addlegendimage{area legend,color=leg#1,fill}
\addlegendentry{$z2=#1$}}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course that can be further automatized, e.g. the minimum and maximum can be extracted from the table, but this deserves IMHO a new question.

Comment: Please see also my answer below. I removed the `scatter` part, because for two colors `blue` and `red` it was easy to name these, but not for three or more used colors. Or do you know a way to "ask" the scatter for its used color?

Comment: @Ben These colors are set in cycle lists. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Are they? A scatter also does so? Maybe, if it results in something like `my legend=\firstcolor`

Comment: @Ben I am a bit lost. What precisely do you want to achieve? You removed scatter but want to reinstall it? And then what?

Comment: I could imagine two ways to get to my desired result. First, using your solution, I question how to specify the color of `my legend` if there are more than two used colors and `scatter` adds `orange` and `dark yellow` and `some odd color`. Second, using my solution (I specify the colors on my own, and I guess this could also be useful, all the more if `z2` is nominal but not ordered), I need to change the color of the first two legend entries

Comment: @Ben Looking at your answer I am wondering if you are secretly looking for `visualization depends on` and/or `point meta`. There is no need to use separate plots with `restrict expr to domain` if you want to change the color depending on the `z1` and/or `z2` values. I guess it would be much simpler for both of us if you edited your question, post the desired output along with some explanations.

Comment: I updated my answer. Is it correct to use `scatter src=explicit,point meta=explicit`?

Comment: @Ben Yes, that's one way. Another one is to use `scatter classes`.

Comment: I updated my question to show my problem

Comment: @Ben I updated my answer to address it.

Comment: You could replace `250` by `(1000/4)` or even by something like `(1000/(MAX-1))`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot)'s many comments pointing me towards `addlegendimage` and `point meta`, I got the following.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\pgfplotstableread{
x y z1 z2
5 5 1  1
6 6 1  2
7 7 2  1
8 8 2  2
}\mytable

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    legend pos=north west
]

\addplot [scatter,scatter src=explicit,point meta=explicit,only marks,mark=*]         table [meta=z2,restrict expr to domain={\thisrow{z1}}{1:1}] {\mytable};
\addplot [scatter,scatter src=explicit,point meta=explicit,only marks,mark=triangle*] table [meta=z2,restrict expr to domain={\thisrow{z1}}{2:2}] {\mytable};

\legend{$z1=1$,%
        $z1=2$}

\addlegendimage{area legend,color=blue,fill}
\addlegendentry{$z2=1$}
\addlegendimage{area legend,color=red,fill}
\addlegendentry{$z2=2$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Outout:**

[image: output]